# LaTeX: splitting the words

Tags: formatting, hyphenation

I have a quite long text, and I sometimes I have words breaking in a weird way, so I wonder if there is some command in LaTeX which will prevent the splitting of words in the whole document?

Comment: If you're not concerned about a justified look, then may be interested in `\raggedright`, or `\RaggedRight` provided by [`ragged2e`](http://ctan.org/pkg/ragged2e).

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/5764) Your question was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Comment: although hyphenation can be suppressed completely, if your document contains a lot of long words, doing so would likely result in very ragged spacing and some overfull lines, and make it more difficult to read, as well as ugly.  better to "correct" individual problems as suggested in the answer by @AndrewSwann.  if certain words are consistently hyphenated incorrectly, see the [tugboat hyphenation exception log](http://mirror.ctan.org/info/digests/tugboat/hyphenex/tb0hyf.pdf) for information on reporting such problems.

Answer (score 29):

If you are writing in a language other than English, then you should use the [babel](http://ctan.org/pkg/babel/) package to change to the hyphenation patterns appropriate for your language.  If there are still some isolated bad hyphenations then you can correct these either by inserting discretionary hyphens `\-` in to the words that give a problem e.g. `dis\-cre\-tion\-ary` or declare hyphenations for such words with the `\hyphenation` command, e.g. put `\hyphenation{dis-cre-tion-ary}` in the preamble.

If you really wish to disable hyphens, then the `babel` package provides the `hyphenrules` environment which can be called with the argument `{nohyphenation}`.  To turn off hyphenation everywhere include the whole body of the document in such an environment. (As Barbara Beeton explains in her comment, usually one does not wish to have this effect, as the resulting output spacing is often poor.)

The document below has the first paragraph set with hypenation rules for Latin and the second set without hypehnation.

**NB** when experimenting with changing languages with `babel`, don't be too put off by errors, you often will have to run latex twice.  This is caused by the way `babel` writes and uses some information in an auxialliary file.

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}

\usepackage[latin]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{hyphenrules}{nohyphenation}
  \lipsum[1]
\end{hyphenrules}
\end{document}
```

[image: Sample output]