# Package for avoiding hyphen in text?

Tags: hyphenation

Is there any package which can be used for avoiding hyphen in text?

Regards

Comment: Why would you want to avoid hyphenation?

Comment: It does not look good to have hyphen in the end of line when word is too long. Is there any way to move that word to next line spread the reaming word in the line.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend it, but have a look at [hyphenat](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/hyphenat).

Comment: Maybe this can help you: [Disable hyphenation in footnotes](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/111409/disable-hyphenation-in-footnotes)

Comment: @manish It ***does*** look good when a word is hyphenated in order to keep non excessive interword spacing.

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/65618/15925